MacOS CoreSpotlight Folder is 300gb
I recently got a notification that I was low on disk space, which is odd because last I had checked a few days ago I still had several hundred gigabytes available. In settings, it said that "System Data" was nearly 400gb, but didn't give any details. Eventually, I found that the CoreSpotlight folder in Users/<me>/Library/Metadata was 336gb, which seems excessive.
Why is this? Are there any files that I can/should delete, or any way to fix this? It's causing me to run so low on disk space that the system keeps hanging and crashing entirely.

In theory, you can delete anything in the user Library, and the Mac will revert to its "new" state; you can of course always test deleting it, because you have a backup that you could restore if needs be.
